# Point local version of a PEAR Package to a development path?

Tags: php, windows, phpunit, pear

I'm trying to fix a bug in a more complex PEAR package (`CodeCoverage`). So I'd like to have the development version that exists not within my PEAR path:

```
c:\Programme\PHP\PEAR\PHP
```

with one on another location, here exemplary:

```
c:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\hakre\PhpstormProjects\php-code-coverage\PHP\
```

Is there a common way in PEAR to temporarily switch from the installed package to just the files on another location of the disk?

I tried with placing a symbolic link, but that does not work because I need to link `CodeCoverage.php` as well which is not possible on Windows XP.

Is there some kind of development switch for this kind of scenario in PEAR or is it just that it's the business of each package to take care of that?

I'm using the `CodeCoverage` package together with `PHPUnit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could get it to work by adding it to PHP's include path *before* the PEAR dir:

```
include_path = ".;c:\path\to\php-code-coverage;C:\programme\php\pear"
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Invoking PHPUnit now uses the standard package *but* the development version of `CodeCoverage`. No symbolic linking required, editing php.ini is enough.

Answer (score 3):

The [**`"Contributing" section of the PHPUnit github project`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) has a runner script included to make that task easier for you.

You can ether check out all the repositories from there or, if you only need one, still use the runner script:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> php -d include_path='.:../phpunit/:../dbunit/:../php-code-coverage/:../php-file-iterator/:../php-invoker/:../php-text-template/:../php-timer:../php-token-stream:../phpunit-mock-objects/:../phpunit-selenium/:../phpunit-story/:/usr/local/lib/php' ../phpunit/phpunit.php $*

(*intentially not formatted as code so the whole thing is shown*)

You can adapt the pathes to an absolute one by replacing `..` with `/path/to/your/dev/folder/` and put the script in `/usr/local/bin/` and call it `phpunit-dev`.

Then it will automatically pick up all the existing folders and fall back to the pear path at the end for everything it can't find.

---

Another way to get a dev setup quickly would be to install it from composer with `minimum-stability: dev` and change the remote on one of the repos :)

Comment: Runner script might be fine, however I was running from within Phpstorm IDE. And I right now only have the one CodeCoverage package I forked on Github. So changing php.ini path works well. But thank you for the answer, I was not aware of that runner script.